# Unused variable error, altought it shouldent

Tags: c++

I`m having some  errors in my c++ program. I need to  create out of 2 sorted list, a 3-rd which is sorted out of the first 2.

```
void arrayInp()
/* Create 2 vectors by the length defined by the user*/
{
int a,b,c,d,i,j;  
Array A,B;    /* HERE i get the error used varaibls, why?*/
int rez[20];
cout<<"enter length of the first array: ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"enter length of the second array: ";
cin>>b;

cout<<"insert first array:";
for (i=0;i<=a;i++)
    cin>>c;
    A.els[i]=c;
    cout<<", ";

cout<<"insert second array:";
for (j=0;j<=a;j++)
    cin>>d;
    B.els[j]=d;
    cout<<", ";
}
```

The header i imported is containing:

```
const int dim = 10; 
struct Array
{
int n;
int els[dim];
};
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Don’t declare variables at the beginning of the function, declare them when you first use (and initialise) them.

Comment: Can you give the exact error message from your compiler ?

Comment: Try to use `//` in C++ for your comments, it's easier on the eyes and the parser because you don't have to bother reading to the end of the line to see if it ends prematurely.

Comment: Can you explain why you use `cin >> c; A.els[i] = c;` instead of `cin >> A.els[i];`? Why would you think the latter won't work?

Answer (score 3):

**The warning possibly comes from `rez`, which you don't use.**

First time I looked at the code, I could tell you're coming from python. The code results in undefined behavior (possibly, depending what indexes get to be):

```
int a,b,c,d,i,j;  
Array A,B;    /* HERE i get the error used varaibls, why?*/

//...

for (i=0;i<=a;i++)
    cin>>c;
    A.els[i]=c;
    cout<<", ";
```

See the error?

```
for (i=0;i<=a;i++)
{
    cin>>c;
}
A.els[i]=c;
cout<<", ";
```

How about now?

Comment: `i` is initialized in the for loop. Where between is it being used without being initialized ? Mr E comment will fix ur issue.

Comment: @giorashc yeah, saw that afterwards, I edited. Still wrong though.

Comment: Thank you guys, constructive comments! and yes i come from python :)
BUT, now my dear eclipse errors me about " A.els[i]=c;" it says els isent cannot be resolved :|

Comment: updated. the  way i would like it to make and as someone  recommend me above.

Comment: @BogdanMaier please post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner, try and get Clang to compile your code. It puts a particular emphasis on digestible error messages.

If you cannot use it, you still have [the online version](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi), though it's limited in terms of dependencies obviously.

```
/tmp/webcompile/_1981_1.cc:18:5: warning: unused variable 'rez' [-Wunused-variable]
int rez[20];
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

You can see, in general, for diagnosis:

- the file, line number and column number where the warning/error is anchored
- the flag which generated the warning, should you choose to disable it
- the source line that produced the output, with a cursor pointing at the position
- finally, it is colored if your terminal supports it, to better identify the various parts (file, error/warning, text, source code, ...)

And for this particular warning: the name of the unused variable is actually shown.

Do yourself a favor, get a friendly compiler ;)

Comment: i use mgwin incapsulated in eclipse  it helps at debuggin but stil l buggs are not to eb found for me....

Comment: But... wait. You have changed the example in your question now so it contains completely different errors! We'll have to start answering all over again.

Comment: well, people asked me above to edit to the new code. and yet the code i`m having now is the one that brought me to the first code.

Comment: @BogdanMaier Oh, I see Lucian has changed it back.

Comment: @BogdanMaier: this is not a forum, so the questions are meant to be rather static. Fortunately, it's all under version control so Luchian was able to revert your question to the first version. Now, if you have a *new* question... then create a *new* question :) The problem with you editing your post is that it invalidates all the answers up until now whilst they could be of use for future users.

Answer (score 0):

`rez` is the unused variable, not `A` or `B`.

And you have several other errors. The braces for one thing. And you ask for more input parameters than the user is prepared to give (in `(i=0;i<=a;i++)`). And you use `a` for an upper boundary instead of `b` in the second block. Copy and paste error?

Comment: Yes. You declare rez, yet never you it. "Unused variable" is just a warning and doesn't prevent the code from compiling and executing. The more serious problem is the lack of braces around the if block mentionen in Luchian's answer.

Comment: You should use an IDE or editor that does auto-indenting. That would help catch such errors before compile time.

Comment: i use eclipse,  i know my code is for now pretty messy but still the issues i have are not synatx mostly... they are weird things which arent seen by error detector... probably because i learned python before i have some issues when it comes to c++ish coding but i`ll   work on that in time :)